# Search form redirecting to search page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

### Summary

**Edit**: After some debugging, it looks like my search method isn't even called when I'm on any non-associated view (i.e. any view except for /search). That's probably why none of my redirection is working; it isn't being called. Now I need to figure out why.

I am using Sphinx to do full-text searching with my Rails application. In summary, have a header in my application.html.erb layout view with a search bar in it. I can successfully search on a given page with that search bar (for example, I can go to localhost:3000/search and the search works), but I can't figure out how to make it so that when a user searches something from any page, they are directed to the search page that contains the results.

As you can see from the code below, I've tried several ways of redirecting: I've put a redirect_to in my search method and I've tried putting it in the respond_to section.

### Question

**How can I change my code such that a user on any page can enter a search term in the header and always be directed to the search page (localhost:3000/search) with their results?**

### Code

**All my code is here:** https://github.com/leesharma/SearchingSandbox

Some key pieces:

routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/search', :to => 'search#search'

  resources :users, :posts

  root :to => 'posts#index'
end
```

`rake routes` (from terminal)

```
   search GET    /search(.:format)         search#search
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root        /                         posts#index
```

Excerpt from shared/_header.html.erb:

```
<div class="small-8 columns">
    <%= form_tag :controller => 'search', :action => 'search', :method => 'get', :authenticity_token => false do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns">
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "button prefix"  %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @posts = Post.search params[:search]
    @users = User.search params[:search]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render json: search_path }
    end
  end
end
```

search.html.erb:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<h2>Listing posts</h2>

<% if @posts %>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.description.first(500) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
<% else %>
    No posts matching your query
<% end %>



<h2>Listing users</h2>

<% if false %> <!-- Leaving this out for now -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>Tagline</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user.first %></td>
                <td><%= user.last %></td>
                <td><%= user.tagline %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>

<% else %>
    No users matching your query
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have submit the answer from mobile, please don't mind about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not calling the search action on your controller, try changing your form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => 'get', :authenticity_token => false) do %>
```

The URL on your browser should change to `localhost:3000/search?&utf8&search=something`.

Comment: I would like to always redirect to the search_path. I've tried putting `format.json { render json: search_path }`, but the page does not successfully redirect to the search page (although the parameter is put into the URL -> http://localhost:3000/?utf8=✓&search=whatevertheusersearches). I've edited my initial post to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Oh, now i understood your problem. A few questions then. Does it give you some error on your console? Where does you application got redirected to?

Comment: I don't get any errors. Basically, when I submit something on my search form, my page does not throw up any error or redirect. The parameters do get passed to the URL though (so, for example, if I search from the users page, the URL becomes http://localhost:3000/users?utf8=✓&search=whatimsearchingfor and on the index page http://localhost:3000?utf8=✓&search=whatimsearchingfor), which, unsurprisingly, doesn't do anything useful. The only page that the search affects is the search page (localhost:3000/search); searching works correctly there.

Comment: My terminal output is clean too: `Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-29 14:08:49 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-07-29 14:08:49] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true `

Comment: Have you tried `format.html redirect_to search_path`? I believe the problem has to do with the absence of some redirecting rule, because you can access the search form from any page, you have to render or redirect to some place.

Comment: I agree that that is likely the issue. I just tried a couple of things. First, I put `respond_to do |format|  format.html redirect_to search_path  format.json { render json: search_path }  end` (with the proper line breaks) but no luck. I also just tried commenting that blog out and instead putting a redirect_to search_path first in my method, but still no redirection or error.

Comment: link_to search_path definitely works as well, so the path itself doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Update, maybe it is a form_tag problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what update do you mean? Updating the ruby/rails version will be difficult since I'm using this as a test before putting the search form in an already-existing, fairly complex application that's still on Rails 3/Ruby 1.9. I did try going to localhost:3000/search while the respond_to ... were in place, and I got the error that Safari encountered too many redirects and could not open the page.

Comment: Aha, got it. Do you mean an issue with form_tag itself? This is the runtime html: `<li class="has-form"> <form> <div class="row collapse"> <div class="small-8 columns"> <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div> <input id="search" name="search" type="text"> </div> <div class="small-4 columns"> <input class="button prefix" type="submit" value="Search"> </div> </div></form> </li>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your form like this:-

```
  <%= form_tag( '/search/search', :method =>  :get )   do %>
    <div class="small-8 columns">
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>
     <div class="small-4 columns">
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "button prefix"  %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
```

I think, you want this bootstrap small-4 class on your text_field, wrap this into your form.
You should have closed div after form `<% end %>`
Hope it will help.Thanks

Comment: I just gave it a try (added the parentheses, switched to '/search/search', and restarted the server for good measure). I also tried 'search#search' and search_path, but no change.

Comment: After some more investigation, you're right in that the search method isn't being called when I'm not on the search page, but I'm not positive as to why. Do you have any other ideas on how to use a form associated with a separate controller than the present page?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be your invalid HTML - you're opening the form tag in one div, then closing that div and opening another. The end result is something like:

```
<div>
  <form ...>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

From the browser's perspective, the submit button is unrelated to the form tag you've created, because it's not nested within in. You will need to restructure your HTML so that the form tag is completely within a single parent element.